# If $λ \neq 0$ an eigenvalue of matrix $A$ then find an eigenvalue of $\text{adj}\left(A\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Any ideas? Do we use the definition of the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call $\text{adj}(A)=B$ and $\text{det}(A)=d$. Then $BA=dI_n$. Suppose $v$ is an eigen vector corresponding to the eigen value $\lambda$ of $A$. Then
\begin{align*}
BAv & = B(\lambda v)\\
&=\lambda Bv.
\end{align*}
But 
\begin{align*}
BAv & = d I_n v\\
&=dv.
\end{align*}
Thus $Bv=\frac{d}{\lambda}v.$
Hence $v$ is an eigen vector of $B$ with the eigen value $\frac{d}{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the equation
$$
\text{adj}(A) A = \det(A) I_n
$$

Comment: Don't we get $adj(A) = 0$ or $A = 0$ here?

Comment: Why? I do not see how you get to this conclusion.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I confused $Iλ - A$ with $A$.

Comment: I still don't understand how I can use that.